# Loop through all the directories and sub-directories with intermediate wildcard patterns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that loops through all the directories but I need to loop through some specific directories only at each level. e.g the path. C:/Main Directory/ABC*/Y/XYZ*/*.edf.

This code gives every file in every directory through recursion. I am unable to edit it so that it give only the sub-directories with a single pattern and the sub-directories of that folder with a single pattern and then it's sub-directories with another single pattern and then only the .edf files in that folder. I could do the .edf files thing though in this code

I'm doing it through these two functions.

```
Function Recursive(FolderPath As String)
Dim Value As String, Folders() As String
Dim Folder As Variant, a As Long
ReDim Folders(0)
If Right(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then Exit Function
Value = Dir(FolderPath, &H10)
Do Until Value = ""
    If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
    Else
        If GetAttr(FolderPath & Value) = 16 Then
            Folders(UBound(Folders)) = Value
            ReDim Preserve Folders(UBound(Folders) + 1)
        Else
            If Count = 4 Then
                temp(0, UBound(temp, 2)) = FolderPath
                temp(1, UBound(temp, 2)) = Value
                temp(2, UBound(temp, 2)) = Count ' FileLen(FolderPath & Value)
                ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp, 1), UBound(temp, 2) + 1)
                End If
        End If
    End If
    Value = Dir
Loop
For Each Folder In Folders
    Count = Count + 1
    Recursive FolderPath & Folder & "\"
    Count = Count - 1
Next Folder
End Function
```

And

```
Public temp() As String
Public Count As Integer
Function ListFiles(FolderPath As String)
Dim k As Long, i As Long
ReDim temp(2, 0)
Count = 1
If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
End If
Recursive FolderPath
k = Range(Application.Caller.Address).Rows.Count
If k < UBound(temp, 2) Then
    MsgBox "There are more rows, extend user defined function"
Else
    For i = UBound(temp, 2) To k
          ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp, 1), i)
            temp(0, i) = ""
            temp(1, i) = ""
            temp(2, i) = ""
    Next i
End If
ListFiles = Application.Transpose(temp)
ReDim temp(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Oberflow. Before posting, please take the time to read our [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section of our help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As obvious this is my first question. Can you please point out what is the problem with the question. I've gone through the help section but I'm unable to figure out.

Comment: There is no actual question being asked. What errors are you reporting in the script that you are using?

Comment: @nbayly This code is for looping through all the directories and files. I am unable to edit it so that it give only the sub-directories with a single pattern and the sub-directories of that folder with a single pattern and then it's sub-directories with another single pattern and then only the .edf files in that folder. I could do the .edf files thing though in this code.

Answer (score 3):

I took a different route with a Scripting.Dictionary object. After creating a directory structure with multiple folders at the ABC and XYZ levels (both matching and non-matching, I populated the final folders with both *.txt and *.edf files.

> <sup>The following procedure loads the Scripting.Dictionary object with **Early Binding**. This requires that **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** be added to the project with the VBE's Tools ► References. For more universality, **Late Binding** can be used by initially dimming the **dFNs** variable as an object and using the [CreateObject method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220083%28v=office.11%29.aspx).</sup>

```
Sub main()
    Dim fm As Long, sFM As String, vFMs As Variant, sMASK As String
    Dim fn As Variant, dFNs As New Scripting.Dictionary

    sFM = Environ("TMP") & "\Main Directory\ABC*\Y\XYZ*\*.edf"
    If UBound(Split(sFM, Chr(42))) < 2 Then Exit Sub  '<~~possibly adjust this safety
    sFM = Replace(sFM, "/", "\")
    vFMs = Split(sFM, Chr(92))

    sMASK = vFMs(LBound(vFMs))
    For fm = LBound(vFMs) + 1 To UBound(vFMs)
        sMASK = Join(Array(sMASK, vFMs(fm)), Chr(92))
        If CBool(InStr(1, vFMs(fm), Chr(42))) Or fm = UBound(vFMs) Then
            build_FolderLevels dFNs, sFM:=sMASK, iFLDR:=Abs((fm < UBound(vFMs)) * vbDirectory)
            sMASK = vbNullString
        End If
    Next fm

    'list the files
    For Each fn In dFNs
        Debug.Print "from dict: " & fn
    Next fn

    dFNs.RemoveAll: Set dFNs = Nothing
End Sub

Sub build_FolderLevels(dFMs As Scripting.Dictionary, _
                       Optional sFM As String = "", _
                       Optional iFLDR As Long = 0)
    Dim d As Long, fp As String, vFMs As Variant

    If CBool(dFMs.Count) Then
        vFMs = dFMs.Keys
        For d = LBound(vFMs) To UBound(vFMs)
            vFMs(d) = vFMs(d) & sFM
        Next d
    Else
        vFMs = Array(sFM)
    End If
    dFMs.RemoveAll

    For d = LBound(vFMs) To UBound(vFMs)
        fp = Dir(vFMs(d), iFLDR)
        Do While CBool(Len(fp))
            dFMs.Add Key:=Left(vFMs(d), InStrRev(vFMs(d), Chr(92))) & fp, _
                     Item:=iFLDR
            fp = Dir
        Loop
    Next d
End Sub
```

To facilitate the recursive behavior, I passed the dictionary keys off to a variant array and then scrubbed the dictionary. Using the elements of the array concatenated with the new wildcard mask, I repopulated the dictionary. Rinse and repeat until all possible combinations had been run through.

Here are the results from the VBE's **Immediate** window.

```
main
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ\Temp2.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ1\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ1\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ1\Temp2.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ2\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ2\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC\Y\XYZ2\Temp2.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ\Temp2.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ1\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ1\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ1\Temp2.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ2\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ2\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC1\Y\XYZ2\Temp2.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ\Temp2.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ1\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ1\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ1\Temp2.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ2\Temp.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ2\Temp1.edf
from dict: t:\TMP\Main Directory\ABC2\Y\XYZ2\Temp2.edf
```

I also ran through several variations on your original wildcard path with similar success.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems great. But My compiler is giving user defined type not defined error at dFNs As New Scripting.Dictionary. I'm new to vba. I'd be greatfull if you could tell me how to solve this.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the stupid questions but I'm out of time. It is giving runtime error at fp = Dir(vFMs(d), iFLDR). The variable vFMs(d) is giving two paths concatenated in a very unusual way. I think that's the issue but but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: I'm afraid I could not reproduce that and it is unlikely that I could without testing it on an exact copy of your directory tree. You could try using conventional backslashes in the string assignment of the original file mask but beyond that, I am not sure what is going on. Obviously, you've changed things from the original as I was working out of my temp folder and you are working out of C:

Comment: I didn't change anything. Just Replaced the link according to the template in your code. However Thanks for your help so for. I'll try to figure out myself from here.

Comment: Could you do this if I send you the original folder if you have enough time? I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: clever idea. it did not work for me, probably because I have some \\*\ in sFM